# Proper way to transform to percentage

Tags: transformation, percentages

This is surely easy but I am somewhat confused. I have a scale 1-7 (7-point-scale) and want to transform them into 0 - 100 (percentage), so 1 = 0% and 7 = 100%.

Do I have to divide 100 by 7 or 6? I ask this because 1 means absolute missing (e.g. 0%).

with dividing by 7 I have to substract 100/7 from 1 to get 0 (1 * 100/7-100/7)

with dividing by 6 I can use the same formula for all numbers: NUMBER * 100/6-100/6.

Comment: There are $6$ intervals, $1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5,5-6,6-7$, so you have to divide by $6$

Comment: Consider the fact that the seventh non-negative $x$-intercept [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/okfqe6crll) is $100.$